# What is the difference between "no. of trials" and "bets count" in Gambler's Ruin simulation?

Tags: java, gambling

Can someone explain this clearly? I am pasting the relevant Java code here. I was thinking number of trials and bets are one and the same.

```
public class Gambler { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int stake = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);    // gambler's stating bankroll
        int goal  = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);    // gambler's desired bankroll
        int T     = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);    // number of trials to perform

        int bets = 0;        // total number of bets made
        int wins = 0;        // total number of games won

        // repeat T times
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {

            // do one gambler's ruin simulation
            int cash = stake;
            while (cash > 0 && cash < goal) {
                bets++;
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) cash++;     // win $1
                else                     cash--;     // lose $1
            }
            if (cash == goal) wins++;                // did gambler go achieve desired goal?
        }

        // print results
        System.out.println(wins + " wins of " + T);
        System.out.println("Percent of games won = " + 100.0 * wins / T);
        System.out.println("Avg # bets           = " + 1.0 * bets / T);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, the program is running a gambling game. The game ends when the player reached a certain amount of money (the 'goal' variable) or zero. The program keeps track of the amount of bets until the money dries up or the goal is met. That is the variable 'bets' or the amount of bets.

The game is repeated several times, denoted by the variable T (number of trials). During each trial, the program, keeps track of the total amount of bets (across trials).

And in the end, the program calculates the average amount of bets. i.e. after playing this game x times, it took this many bets per game, on average.